# Django-oscar facet search using solr

Tags: django, faceted-search, django-oscar

Iam using django-oscar for my ecommerce project. In that, Iam getting filter facets in results page when i search any term using search box. Thats fine and I want the filter facets in browse page without giving any search term.

Can anyone help me is there any method available to take facets in home page or should i need to customize oscar for browse page?

Comment: I think the filter facets are available on the browse page by default. I use django oscar 1.2 and I get it on the browse page